# Select an option to retrieve it's row from database MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that should retrieve all the row form the database based on a selection from the same row.

***HTML & PHP Code***

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Brand Name</th>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                            <th>Model Number</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Description</th>
                            <th>Part Number</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">QTY</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">Unit Price (SR)</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">Total Price (SR)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?php
                                    $query = $con->query("SELECT products_itemDescription FROM pruc_products"); // Run your query --> For Item Desc.
                                    echo '<select class="form-control" id="DescriptionS2forms" name="itemDescription">'; // Open your drop down box

                                    echo '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled></option>'; //Empty Value for VALIDATION
                                    // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
                                    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                       echo '<option value="'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'">'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
                                 ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestQTY" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestUnit" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1000000" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" id="deleteBtn">
                                <a class="btn btn-default deleteBtn">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I have this selection as defined it is fetched from the database so I need every "Record" to be fetched also but based on the selection I'll make from the selection tab.

***PHP & SQL Query***

```
<?php
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT products_brandName FROM pruc_products WHERE products_brandName, products_itemDescription = (products_id)") ; 
    $sql->execute() ;
    while( $row = $sql->fetch()):
        echo '<strong>'.$row['products_brandName'].'</strong>';
endwhile ?>
```

any help for this?

Comment: Ask Yourself. Is This The Correct Way To Use **Where Clause** In "*..WHERE products_brandName, products_itemDescription =*"?

Comment: however I know it's wrong I was trying

You have better comment?

Answer (score 0):

`products_barndName` needs to equal something. Also, don't use a comma to separate your conditions in a WHERE clause. Try this:

```
WHERE products_brandName = 'x' AND products_itemDescription = (products_id)
```

Comment: didn't get me also what I need

Comment: Are you passing off the product name and product ID to PHP?

Comment: Thanks, I found the way